# Why in Azure pipelines driver path is not correct and executed like linux instead of win

Tags: python, azure, continuous-integration, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

I want to execute my auto tests in Azure pipeline but I got the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Bu chrome.exe is located by this path and there is should not be any issue. So, as per my initial investigation the issue related to the fact that in Azure pipelines it is trying to get chromedriver by following path:

```
WDM:logger.py:16 Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
INFO     WDM:logger.py:16 Driver [/home/vsts/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/102.0.5005.61/chromedriver] found in cache
```

As you can see there is indicated linux64, but look up the below logs from my local machine.

Locally if I am trying to run the same test cases I see the different path and everything is running and passed correctly. Since there is win32, not linux64.

```
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 102.0.5005
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 102.0.5005 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\AYTAN\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
```

So I can't understand why on my local machine the path to chromedriver is correct but in Azur pipelines it is not correct. How I can fix it? Maybe I can indicate it directly in my code? My Python code is below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_chrome_options():
    options = chrome_options()
    options.add_argument('chrome')
    options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    options.chrome_driver_binary = r"C:\Users\USER\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\102.0.5005.61\chromedriver.exe"
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    return options

@pytest.fixture
def get_webdriver(get_chrome_options):
    options = get_chrome_options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    return driver
```

Answer (score 0):

- Give relative path instead the entire path that might help.

for eg:

```
./testapp/console-app/chrome.exe
```

- You can also give absolute path too but here the root directory
  changes it becomes `Build.SourcesDirectory` . It is at this directory
  where the source code is downloaded.

for eg:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/testapp/console-app/chrome.exe
```

**Reference:**

[Directories in azure devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)